# Android : How to simply add categories/Separators/Section header in my list view?

Tags: android, listview, categories

I made a list view using this way :

```
String[] list = {"1","2","3","A","B","C"};

Widget_List_Adapter adapter = new Widget_List_Adapter(this, list);

//set the onItemClickListener as usual
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);

//set our custom list item listener for the extra functions
adapter.setListener(this);

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Now how can I simply add some categories ?

Answer (score 0):

you must maintain custom adapter for implementing categories into your listview. take a look at this [tutorial](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-sectioned-headers-in-listviews/)